# Interacting with ActiveX control on web page using external PowerShell script

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, com, activex, aurigma

I'm trying to develop an automation script using PowerShell that will log in to a website, fill out a form, and upload one or more files.  Logging in and form-filling are trivially easy using IE's COM interface.  However, the website uses an ActiveX control (Aurigma Uploader) to do the file uploading.

Is there a way to reference this control from PowerShell?  I am hoping that once this is done, I can call various methods in the control and hopefully get it to do what I want.

Also, the website is not under my control, so doing this inside the browser (javascript) is not possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're already interacting with IE's DOM, you could just execScript() and pass in whatever JS to interact with the ActiveX you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload files through Aurigma Uploader without end user interaction. This is done by design due to security reasons.

I.e. there is no API for adding files to upload list even if you can get reference to control.